# Tridion Content Service returning no value for pageContent query

Tags: dd4t

I am facing issue in retrieving PageContent using content service. The content service returning results for other queries like(pages, componentpresentation,components). Someone please help me if any caching is not serving then how to invalidate the caching?

**Content Service Query:**

http://dev-cms:9085/client/v2/content.svc/Pages(ItemId=214020,PublicationId=262)/PageContent

**Response:**
Unable to build feed/entry based on input: No resource was found for the requested item

Comment: Looks like you are using one of the OData endpoints of the content service. These endpoints are not meant to be used directly, but only through the CIL (which is an SDK available for Java and .NET). If you are using the CIL, can you please share how you are using that?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the (legacy) OData V2 API actually *is* a public API.  Indeed, the OData V4 API is not public and should only be used through the CIL.

Answer (score 2):

Is the page content stored in the database too? IIRC, if pages are published to the file system, their content is not accessible through the content service.